# Hoping for Tweak-assistance: Coding for adding up multiple drop-down fields html not working yet

Tags: javascript, html, forms, paypal, addition

Best to you today! Im Requesting a bit of insight/help with some javascript in this form that adds up the priced selections from more than 1 priced-dropdown menu of a paypal button to a total cost. It's almost working but the selected option(s) from the first 3 dropdown menus in the example are not successfully being passed along to the total cost field. (as you can see only one is monetized here this time).  Its that the Javascript for the arithmetic is slightly off or missing something but i cant see it yet!

2nd question::  How can i most directly successfully add a third priced dropdown menu to be figured into the total cost.  Thank you already. "Stack" is a pretty fierce resource.

3rd question: Im Highly interested in turning the "Total cost" text input field into a read-only flat output figure.

Found the answer thanks!